# Select string FROM in Grafana InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have some sales data in InfluxDB, basically every 10 seconds I record the total number of sales from SQL, then break that down into sales of different items in the fields.
So a row might look like:

```
time        Bicycles Shovels Hats Candles Sales
01/01/2019     12       6      2     4      24
02/01/2019     14       9      3     5      31
```

(This is dummy data for this question and doesn't reflect the number in the images, which are from production tests I've been doing with actual data)

It's important to stress this is accumulative, each entry grows by the number of sales.

I can then use Grafana to show me the difference(max(sales)) group by time(1d) to show the total sales (per day in this case)

[image]

What I am also trying to do is show the most sales per group (day) in a table, a record sales table, how well we have done in the past.

So I have 3 queries in Grafana:

```
SELECT time, max(difference) FROM (
   SELECT difference(max("Sales")) 
   FROM "autogen"."Paid_Orders" 
   WHERE $timeFilter 
   GROUP BY time(1d) fill(none)
)
```

Swap "sales" for bicycles and hats (whatever) in the subsequent queries and I end up with a table that looks like:

[image: Example results table]

Problem is I don't know which line is which field. Normally (in SQL) I would do something like SELECT 'Sales' as Type, etc... to add in a column with "Sales" in it. But I can't see that as an option in either Grafana or Influx.

1. Am I recording the data wrong and could I be leveraging Tags for this?
2. How can I identify the rows in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your data structure doesn't look good. Instead of one record:

```
time        Bicycles Shovels Hats Candles Sales
01/01/2019     12       6      2     4      24
```

save  multiple records with different `item` tag (sales is int field):

```
time           item      sales 
01/01/2019     Bicycles  12  
01/01/2019     Shovels   6
01/01/2019     Hats      2
01/01/2019     Candles   4
```

Then group by time AND `item` tag + SPREAD function can be used to remove subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT time, SPREAD(sales) 
FROM "autogen"."Paid_Orders" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time(1d), "item" fill(none)
```

Comment: Thank's I'm going to try this, the thought occurred last night, but I was unsure. I'll give it ago. I started with SPREAD but I seemed to be getting some weird results. Maybe that'll change when I put the data in properly.